# Ucanaccess throwing exception

Tags: ms-access, ucanaccess

When I am trying to fetch data from access database ucanaccess driver is throwing this exception
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.4 data type cast needed
 for parameter or null literal
here is the screen of my application output
[image]
 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ... WHERE ? = ?
```

Parameter placeholders cannot be used to specify column names. You'll need to use dynamic SQL (string formatting) to specify the column *name* and then use a parameter placeholder for the column *value*.

Comment: Thanks Gord Thompson